# RegSetValueEx() not changing the key value

Tags: c++, winapi

In my application, when I first set the key-value using RegSetValueEx() it works, but when I try to change the value using the same function it doesn't work, the value remains same. What am I doing wrong ?

Here is the code :

```
SetSZValue( "MyAppData", "versionInfo", "1.0.0" );


    HKEY CreateKey( string regkey )
    {
         HKEY hKey ;
         DWORD disValue ;

         char msg[512] ;

         string _key = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\" ;
                _key += regkey ;

         LONG retValue = RegCreateKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, regkey.c_str(), 0, 0, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, 0, &hKey, &disValue ) ;
         if (retValue != ERROR_SUCCESS)
         {
             FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, GetLastError(), 0, &msg[0], 512, 0 ) ;
             MessageBox( 0, &msg[0], "CreateKey", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );
         }

         return hKey ;
    }



    void SetSZValue( string regkey, string keyName, string keyValue )
    {
         HKEY hKey;
         DWORD disValue;

         char msg[512];

         hKey = CreateKey(regkey);
         if (hKey)
         {
            LONG retValue = RegSetValueEx( hKey, keyName.c_str(), 0, REG_SZ, ( const BYTE* )( keyValue.c_str() ), keyValue.size()+1 );
            if ( retValue != ERROR_SUCCESS )
            {
                FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, GetLastError(), 0, &msg[0], 512, 0 );
                  MessageBox( 0, &msg[0], "SetSZValue", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );
            }

                RegCloseKey ( hKey );
         }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide minimal, but *complete* example?

Comment: It's all that is there, the function is called like this : SetSZValue( "MyAppData", "versionInfo", "1.0.0" ); I have also updated in the above

Comment: Not sure how this works at all.  But did you forget to press F5 in Regedit.exe so it updates the displayed value?

Comment: No I did not, I have even tried clearing the registry of entries set by my application and try again, but every time the result is same, besides my application extract the value from the registry on every startup and displays it, so even after changing the value it is still showing the same value.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I seem to have the same problem.

Comment: Ok, just got it (in my case).  I was trying to change the value of a key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` without running as administrator.  `RegSetValueEx` failed silently - returned `ERROR_SUCCESS` but didn't change the key.  Running as admin solved this.

Answer (score 1):

`RegSetValueEx` accepts the name of the value inside the key to change; not the name of the key. Supply the value name instead; the key name comes from the `HKEY` itself.

Comment: You mean the second parameter in RegSetValueEx ? MSDN says lpValueName = The name of the value to be set. If a value with this name is not already present in the key, the function adds it to the key. The second last parameter is value lpData.

Comment: Yes, I mean the second parameter. Note that it says "name present **in the key**"; not name **of the key**. What is the name of the value that you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Is your app a 32-bit process running on a 64-bit Windows version?  If so, does your app have a UAC manifest with a "requestedExecutionLevel" value in it?  If not, your key may be getting virtualized to another section of the Registry and you are simply not looking in the right place.  [Registry Virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884.aspx) is a feature of WOW64 so legacy 32-bit and 64-bit processes do not step over each other in the Registry.  You should install SysInternals [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), it will show you which keys and values your app is actually accessing.

Comment: Yes its a 32 bit process and it has the manifest with "requestedExecutionLevel" set to "requireAdministrator". I think that's not the problesm.

Comment: Then you really should install Process Monitor and see what your app is really accessing.